# Make TeXstudio spell check all files

Tags: texstudio, spelling

I have my document split up and referenced by a root document in the form of;

```
\input{path/to/file}
```

I can currently trigger a spell check on the current document by using *Tools > Check Spelling*.

Is it possible to trigger a spell check across all files referenced by the root document?

Comment: That's currently not supported in TeXstudio.